# Pivotal question about bootstrap confidence intervals

Tags: bootstrap, pivot

I'm reading through Efron's work on bootstrapping and I have a few questions. There are a few assumptions that are eluded to but not *really* explicitly stated.

**(1)** Do we have to have a statistic that can be made into a pivot? That is, do we need something like $\bar{X}$ which has a pivot $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$? It seems to me that it would be sensible. We use pivots to derive such formulas.

For example, what if I want to consider a bootstrapping interval for $\sigma$ for non-normal data? I'd have to (a) derive the distribution of $\sigma$, (b) find a pivot, and (c) complete bootstrapping on the pivot from (b)? If we're doing the work to find the pivot, why not just use the mathematical statistician approach of deriving the parametric interval?

It seems that resampling for the empirical distribution is sensible regardless of whether we have a pivot. That is, the empirical distribution should still approach the true distribution as the sample size grows (as long as the sample is good). Is it that bootstrapping "works" but is "better" when the statistic can be made a pivot?

**(2)** The percentile bootstrap confidence interval is attractive for its simplicity. Resample and take the appropriate quantiles. In addition to the pivot language, there's an added statement about the symmetry of $\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{X})-\theta$ or some (unknown function) $g(\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{X}))-g(\theta)$.

Efron does a simple example in the textbook (p.172) where they compare the bootstrap distribution to the asymptotic distribution but I don't see how you'd check this in practice, where you may not know the true or asymptotic sampling distribution.

If it involves (a) finding the pivot and (b) finding the function $g(\cdot)$ as well as (c) knowing the true/asymptotic distribution to evaluate bias then why not just use the mathematical statistician approach?

I know the BCa interval is preferred because it adjusts for bias (and I think the undercover of the percentile approach), but I'm curious how we could see whether this issue needs to be addressed when calculating a percentile interval.